# JQuery Searchbar Not Hiding Divs Correctly

Tags: jquery, html, angular

I have a set up where my `<user-panel>` elements are created through an `ng-repeat`. The children of this element are divs with the class `user-panel-name`. I have been trying to use the text contained in the name to filter the results on the page, taking the value of an input box.

I've tried the following...

```
$("#user-search-input").on('keyup', function () {

    var search = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    console.log(search);

    $(".user-panel").show().filter(function () {
        return $(this).find('user-panel-name').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) < 0;
    }).hide();
});
```

This one did not run at all.

I changed the method to be called in onKeyUp instead..

```
function SearchUsers(e){
    var search = $(e).val().toLowerCase();
    console.log(search);

    $(".user-panel").show().filter(function () {
    return $(".user-panel").find('user-panel-name').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) < 0;
    }).hide();
}
```

The second method ran fine but was hiding all elements all the time. Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: No errors in the console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix my issue by implementing the follow function instead.

```
function searchUsers(e){
  var search = $(e).val().toLowerCase();

  $(".user-panel").each(function (){
    if ($(this).find('.user-panel-name').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) < 0){
      $(this).hide();
    }else {
      $(this).show();
    }
  })
}
```

I'm unsure how or why exactly my original implementation didn't work but after a few head scratches I took this approach instead.